# Changing height of input element doesn't let me enter text block

Tags: html, css

Given the tag

```
<input type = "text">
```

I want to increase the height of that element so users can type a lot more.

However, when I change the height of the input, the text still appears in the middle and doesn't go top left to bottom right (the standard way text goes). How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Input tag is for single line text input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An input will only be one line high. What you're looking for is a textarea.

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```